# Div tag mixed with php code working in Firefox, not in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, compatibility

I am trying to set a style for the statement inside echo. It works fine in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer. Help me. Any suggestions will be helpful

```
 $nav .= "<div class='current'> $page </div>";

  $nav .= " <a onclick='showPage(\"".$page."\")'><div class='other'> $page </div></a> ";

$prev  = "<a class='lin' onclick='showPage(\"".$page."\")'> Prev</a>";
```

This is how its looking   http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/3957144073/

Comment: Can you show the code not working?

Comment: more information please.

Comment: I added more info @ James Black

Comment: still it isn't clear .. if you want help with css, you got to post it here or be more clear.

Comment: I am not seeing where you set the style, just setting class values for elements.

What does your HTML look like in the browser?  We need to see what the browser sees to see what may be going wrong.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/3957144073/   This is how its looking

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, by looking at the flickr screenshot, it appears that IE is not loading your style sheet.

You may want to use IE8, and basically hit F12 to bring up the developer app, and see what is happening on IE.